# Replace letters with stars in password field with gcc

Tags: c, gcc

How to put stars `*` in the password field when user enters password?

In turbo we can use `getch()` but it is not available in gcc.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What platform are you developing on?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `termios(3)` to control various characteristics of the terminal, such as whether or not it echoes typed characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use the tcsetattr(3) function.  In your termios structure, you'll need to unset ICANON (canonical mode), and ECHO (character echo).  Then you can read the characters from the input one at a time, outputting an asterisk after each character input.